# Updating sqlite DB from remote MySQL DB best approach

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, swiperefreshlayout

I am creating an app that will have many records in the future and I need to update the local sqlite database from my remote mysql database but I am not sure if what I have done is the best approach .. these are the steps that I have done up until now using the swipe to refresh feature when the user pulls to refresh:

1. Retrieve data (products from allproducts table) from MySQL using Retrofit
2. Delete old products records in allproducts table in my local sqlite database
3. Insert retrieved products from remote database into allproducts table in local database
4. View the data in a recyclerview list

I'm quite new to this way so I am not sure if what I am doing is the right way..I wanted to get the same results like in gmail app or twitter..I don't want to only use remote database when refreshing I want to allow the users to use the updated list even when they are offline or something like caching the mysql data received..I hope you understand what I mean..can someone please advice or guide me.. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Comment: @DavidMedenjak thanks I have seen this but what I want is to keep the synced database available even if there's no internet connection. Is my way not good for this kind of behavior?